# ios 10 load view and viewwillappear is not called after presenting a viewcontroller from UInavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have the following code to launch the passcode viewcontroller from navigation controller. This code works everytime except the first launch of the app. Because of this the application is not presented with a lock screen when it launches. After it is launched for every sleep mode the pass code VC is presented. I found out that when the app launches the loadView and viewwillappear is not getting called the first time. Any help on this is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
    _passcodeViewController = [[KKPasscodeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    _passcodeViewController.mode = KKPasscodeModeEnter;
    _passcodeViewController.hideCancel = YES;
    _passcodeViewController.delegate = self;
    _passcodeViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    _passcodeViewController.isLaunchingVideoCall = isLaunchingVideoCall;

    _passcodeCompletion = nil;

    _passcodeNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_passcodeViewController];
    UINavigationController* rootNav = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    [rootNav presentViewController:_passcodeNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: where do you run your code of presenting the VC?

Comment: This code you posted... is in which function?

Comment: I run the code in applicationWillFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Basically i call a function that runs this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed NibName,
your code look like this

```
_passcodeViewController = [[KKPasscodeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KKPasscodeViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry there is no Nib used